# rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU + watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s

Tags: kernel, lockup, watchdog, scheduler

Being unable to ssh into a machine I connected it to a monitor and found the following:

[image]

The machine is running Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS and is a first generation 8 core Ryzen 1700. I've restarted the machine since and it works fine but am not sure what caused this in the first place and want to avoid it happening again.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

From: [What are all these "Bug: soft lockup" messages about?](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7017652)

> ### Situation
>
> In the system log (/var/log/messages or journalctl) a lot of the
>   following messages is printed.
>
> ```
> May 25 07:23:59 XXXXXXX kernel: [13445315.881356] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#16 stuck for 23s! [yyyyyyy:81602]
> ```
>
> followed by various stack traces. This document tries to explain what
>   the soft lockup messages mean.

The error message itself doesn't tell you what is causing the problem.

> ### Cause
>
> A 'soft lockup' is defined as a bug that causes the kernel to loop in
>   kernel mode for more than 20 seconds, without giving other tasks a
>   chance to run. The watchdog daemon will send an non maskable interrupt
>   (NMI) to all CPUs in the system who in turn print the stack traces of
>   their currently running tasks.

Reducing server load is normal solution:

> ### Resolution
>
> Under normal circumstances those messages may go away if the load
>   decreased. This 'soft lockup' can happen if the kernel is busy,
>   working on a huge amount of objects which need to be scanned, freed or
>   allocated respectively. The stack traces of those tasks can give a
>   first idea what the tasks were doing. However, to be able to examine
>   the cause behind the messages, a kernel dump would be needed.
>
> You cannot disable those messages, however in some situations
>   increasing the time when those soft lockups will be fired can relax
>   the situation.
>
> Do do so just increase the following `sysctl` parameter:
>   `kernel.watchdog_thresh` Default value for this parameter is `10` and
>   to double the value might be a good start.